# Can't install software, dpkg returns error while processing python3-distupgrade

Tags: apt, lubuntu, dpkg

Installation of software results in the following error:

```
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:0.190.2) ...
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 289, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 283, in main
    process.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 809, in communicate
    self.stdin.close()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os
EOFError: EOF read where not expected

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 289, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 283, in main
    process.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 809, in communicate
    self.stdin.close()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
dpkg: error processing python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:0.190.2); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:0.190.2); however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:0.190.2); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up geany-common (1.22+dfsg-2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                Setting up geany (1.22+dfsg-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-distupgrade
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`'sudo dpkg --configure -a` didn't solve the problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `python` solved the problem. Reïnstalling `python` gave the same error. While I do not use `python3` I do not mind. But it seems a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting:

```
E: Sub-process error (1) after do-release-upgrade
```

Try these commands below:

```
sudo
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/initramfs-tools.post*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/initramfs-tools.pre*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/bcmwl-kernel-source.post*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/bcmwl-kernel-source.pre*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I hope this helps you!